# C# - Method name expected error when returning variable?

Tags: c#, methods, return

I'm just trying to return a double value in a method, but I keep getting "method name expected" on the return variable line:

```
public class Rectangle
{
    private double height;
    private double width;

    public Rectangle(double h, double w)
    {
        height = h;
        width = w;
    }

    public double perimeter()
    {
        double perimeter = ((2 * height) + (2 * width));
        return perimeter();
    }
```

It seems like this should be simple enough, I can't figure out what's going wrong! I've tried changing the variable name to something else but Visual Studio INSISTS I need to put the method name on the return line, instead of the variable I'm trying to return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better not to name your variables same as methods.

Correct declaration would be:

```csharp
public double Perimeter()
{
    double perimeter = ((2 * height) + (2 * width));
    return perimeter;
}
```

or

```csharp
public double Perimeter()
{
    return ((2 * height) + (2 * width));
}
```

or single-liner

```csharp
public double Perimeter() => ((2 * height) + (2 * width));
```

or a property (from @ckuri comment)

```csharp
public double Perimeter => ((2 * height) + (2 * width));
```

Comment: Though conceptually what he is doing here should be rather a property instead of a method (action), i.e. `public double Perimeter => ((2 * height) + (2 * width));`.

Comment: @ckuri yes, this is pretty valid too

Comment: Interestingly capitalizing the method name didn't change its mind, so I ended up returning the line of math directly. Thanks for the help!